# How to configure network between ec2 servers and remote workstations?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpn, firewall

I have several ec2 servers and ten remote workstations all over the world.
Both servers and workstations may be windows or linux.
The servers have static IP, the workstations don't.
I need to configure the network in such way that:

- all workstations can access all servers on all ports.
- all servers can access all servers on all ports(in/out).
- all servers are completely closed to the rest of the world except of previous rules

I can accept installing software to support the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **[AWS Client VPN](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/12/introducing-aws-client-vpn-to-securely-access-aws-and-on-premises-resources/)**, that does exactly what you need.

Hope that helps :)